# Orbit of a transverse manifold under the action of an algebraic group

Tags: geometric-invariant-theory

Consider an algebraic group acting on a affine manifold. Suppose that S is an affine submanifold transverse to the action. Are there some conditions on the group, the action or S such that the orbit of S under the group is the whole space ?